# Python-Config installed but not found when installing wxPython in env

Tags: wxpython, python-config

I am trying to install install wxpython using `python3 -m pip install wxpython` I have a HP x86 machine with a new install of Ubuntu18.04.3 LTS. I have setup a python env and have Python 3.6.9. when I run the above command in the environment I get

```
 `python-config                            : not found
    Checking for library python3.6m in LIBDIR : not found
    Checking for library python3.6m in python_LIBPL : yes
    Checking for header Python.h                    : Distutils not installed? Broken python installation? Get python-config now!
```

I have installed python:

```
python3 -m pip install python-config
Requirement already satisfied: python-config in ./PrintrunEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

and have checked the PATH:

```
>>> import sys
   >>> for p in sys.path:
   ...     print(p)
   ... 

   /usr/lib/python36.zip
   /usr/lib/python3.6
   /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
   /home/colin/Printrun/PrintrunEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what is going on here and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The `python-config` in the error message above refers to a script installed with Python's development tools package, not a Python package. Take a look at https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html to find info about system packages you need to have installed in order for pip to build wxPython.